# Generate Random Questions in Database

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I have 5 table in Sqlite Database:
1.maths 
2.boilogy 
3.chemestry 
4.physics 
5.GK.

in all tables 10 Question. and finally we generate random question in test page
so what the Query in Sq lite database

```
public ArrayList<ExamModel> getRandomQuestion() {

    ArrayList<ExamModel> list = new ArrayList<ExamModel>();
    ExamModel model = null;

    Cursor cursor = null;

    cursor=myDataBase.query(tbl_MST_CA+","+tbl_MST_Exam+","+tbl_MST_Geography, null, null, null, null, null, "RANDOM()","15");


    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            model = new ExamModel();

            model.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id")));
            model.setAns1(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Answer1")));
            model.setAns2(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Answer2")));
            model.setAns3(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Answer3")));
            model.setAns4(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Answer4")));
            model.setQuestion(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("Question")));
            model.setTrueAnswer(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("TrueAnswer")));
            model.setLevelId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("LevelId")));
            model.setExamId(cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("ExamIdRef")));

            list.add(model);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();


    return list;
}
```

Comment: What is the unexpected behavior that you are getting?

Comment: what if you random before queriying? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: i m getting all the time same record @Prerak Sola

Comment: If all the tables have the same structure, you can put the table names in an array, use random to pick a random table. After that, you can count the number of rows, generate a random number in that range and pick that question. You might need to add an `id` or `number field` in the table structure for selecting the question.

Comment: actually i want a records from all the tables so using that i don't think its work because they might get only table records

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood that. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: i want random question from all the tables records for ex i m having 6 tables and want only 15 records form all of them.